# Adding custom admin panel to laravel with authentication system

Tags: laravel

Hi I am trying to add a custom admin panel to my laravel project. I have a login page. After entering valid email and password user can login to dashboard. But **Problem is when i enter valid email and password it always stay in the login screen.**

Here is my login form

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{{ route('admin.login') }}" method="post">
                    {!! csrf_field() !!}
                        <fieldset>

                            <div class="input-prepend" title="Email">
                                <span class="add-on"><i class="halflings-icon user"></i></span>
                                <input class="input-large span10" name="email" required   maxlength="100"  id="email" type="text" placeholder="type useremail"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>

                            <div class="input-prepend" title="Password">
                                <span class="add-on"><i class="halflings-icon lock"></i></span>
                                <input class="input-large span10" name="password" required id="password" type="password" placeholder="type password"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>

                            <label class="remember" for="remember"><input type="checkbox" id="remember" />Remember me</label>

                            <div class="button-login">  
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
```

Here is my route

```
Route::get('/admin/login', [
     'as' => 'admin.login', 
     'uses' => 'AdminController@getLogin'
]);
Route::post('/admin/login', [
     'as' => 'admin.login', 
     'uses' => 'AdminController@postLogin'
]);


Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'
    ], function () {
    Route::get('/admin', [
     'as' => 'dashboard', 
     'uses' => 'AdminController@index']);
    Route::get('/logout', [
     'as' => 'logout',
     'uses' => 'AdminController@getLogout'  
]);
});
```

Here is my admin Controller

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Auth;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('admin.admin_master');  
    }
    public function getLogin() 
    {
        return view('admin.admin_login');
    }
    public function postLogin(Request $request) 
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required'
            ]);
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request['email'], 'password' => $request['password']])) {
            // Authentication passed...
            return redirect()->route('dashboard');
        }
        return redirect()->back()->with(['fail' => 'Could not Login']);
    }
    public function getLogout()
    {
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect()->route('admin.login');
    }
}
```

Here is Authenticate.php

```
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
class Authenticate
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
            if ($request->ajax()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            } else {
                return redirect()->guest(route('admin.login'))->
                withError('You must be logged in !');
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: It always stays at login screen or just when you enter valid email and password ?

Comment: when i enter valid email and password.

Comment: can you accees `dashboard` route? and check whether`Auth::attempt` returns true or false.

Comment: I checked, Auth::attempt return true, and dsahboard route redirect me to login screen as i place the route in the middleware . If  i do not use meddleware all works fine but problem is after login if i press back button it loged me out.

Comment: Please provide the Middleware file.  And check the log file if there is any error shown there or not.

Comment: Added authenticate.php from middleware folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this middleware

```
public function __construct(Guard $auth)
{
    $this->auth = $auth;
}

/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($this->auth->guest()) {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        } else {
            return redirect('/admin/login'); //edited line
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Try using absolute route instead of using it's alias.

Comment: Gives error
InvalidArgumentException in UrlGenerator.php line 307:
Route [admin/login] not defined.
Sorry i used guest(route('/admin/login))
Now i changed to guest('/admin/login'), but nothing happen, page just reload

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it using Auth:login($array). Change your code to

```
public function postLogin(Request $request) 
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required'
        ]);
    $data = $request->input();

    if(Auth::login($data)){
     return redirect('/dashboard');

  }
    return redirect()->back()->with(['fail' => 'Could not Login']);
}
```

Comment: Gives error
ErrorException in SessionGuard.php line 418:
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of Illuminate\Http\Request given

Comment: Then data is not coming on this method. You can grab the data in this way: $data = $request->input(); then pass it through Auth::login($data).

Answer (score 0):

May be it's redirect to login page, because both of your route are same for view `getLogin` and `postLogin`. Try to use `action()` method instead of `route()` in form action. Ex:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{{ action('AdminController@postLogin') }}" method="post">
    // other codes....
</form>
```

**Tips:** If you are using Laravel 5.2 put all of your route inside `'middleware'=>'web'`. Ex:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    // put your routes here.......
}
```

Comment: {{ action('AdminController@postLogin') }} does'n do anything, still stay in login page.
If i use Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']] instead of Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'] it works but problem is after login when i press back button it log out and again press forward button it login to dashboard. How can i solve this problem

Comment: @NishanSingha Going back doesn't logout a user. The user will stay login to server till you logout. Logout the user instead of going back.